# Decimate Planar Blender Not Responding on Big Mesh

Tags: modifiers

Currently trying to apply the Decimate Planar modifier to a big mesh (400 000 faces) with angle=30 and Blender just stays stuck on it when I try to apply it (I removed the preview). I tried letting it run overnight but even that doesn't do anything.

Is there any alternative I can use? Any solution I might be missing? I'm open to code/script solutions if there's some savvy people willing to help!

Thanks